# Truncate text in multiple spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have two spans with text:

```
<span id="text1">text1</span>
<span id="text2">text2</span>
```

These two texts have different styles so I cannot combine them in the same span. They are also on the same line. I want to truncate the result on one line. I tried wrapping the two spans in a div and apply truncation to that div but it does not work. What else can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to post the CSS, too.